# Combobox duplicate entry and binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a strange issue with a combobox.  The control is bound to a collection that contains a duplicate item, albeit with different case.

They are populated in the list, via databinding, as such:

Babu
BABU

Within the application that I am creating, case is important and both items need to be displayed.

I have the selected item as BABU, yet when I open the combobox, the selectted item immediately changes to Babu without any further intervention from me.  I am not handling the DropDownOpening event anywhere so there is no logic there that is causing this.

My suspicions are that it's to do with the databinding not liking what it see's as duplicate entries but I cannot be sure about this.

Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: How are Equals and GetHashCode implemented in your class (the one that shows in combobox).

Comment: @Nikolay, The combobox is bound to a string property of a class that does not implement Equals or GetHashCode.  Would that make a difference with binding?

Comment: I cant reproduce it in a simple sample application. Can you give us more code? Your xaml, your code for source class. How do you select item in code

Comment: Can you show us the code for where you select BABU with your combobox? I'd also like to know if you're trying to select the string value or the underlying class.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Designer code for that form and confirm that BABU and Babu are included in your autocomplete list for that combobox. This happened to me once where I fixed it on the form designer but it never synced up with the form designers code and it ended up containing old unwanted selections.

Also check out your autocomplete modes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx